# Как в кнопку добавить картинку?

Tags: html, css

Я хочу сделать картинку как кнопку

```
<button><img src="Button1.png" style=".Button1 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 88px;
  top: 86px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  z-index: 2;
}"></button>
```

Получается кнопка с картинкой. И как убрать всё что за картинкой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы указали стили для `.Button1`, но не используете нигде этот класс.

```css
button {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 88px;
  top: 86px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  z-index: 2;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/Disk_pack1.svg/1200px-Disk_pack1.svg.png"></button>
```